# Automatic post-registration user authentication

Tags: php, symfony, registration

We're building a business app from the ground up in Symfony 2, and I've run into a bit of a snag with the user registration flow: after the user creates an account, they should be automatically logged in with those credentials, instead of being immediately forced to provide their credentials again.

Anyone had any experience with this, or able to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**Symfony 4.0**

This process hasn't changed from Symfony 3 to 4 but here is an example using the newly recommended `AbstractController`. Both the `security.token_storage` and the `session` services are registered in the parent `getSubscribedServices` method so you don't have to add those in your controller.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use YourNameSpace\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class LoginController extends AbstractController{

    public function registerAction()
    {    
        $user = //Handle getting or creating the user entity likely with a posted form
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $this->container->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
        // The user is now logged in, you can redirect or do whatever.
    }

}
```

**Symfony 2.6.x - Symfony 3.0.x**

As of Symfony 2.6 `security.context` is deprecated in favor of `security.token_storage`. The controller can now simply be:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use YourNameSpace\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class LoginController extends Controller{

    public function registerAction()
    {    
        $user = //Handle getting or creating the user entity likely with a posted form
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
    }

}
```

While this is deprecated you can still use `security.context` as it has been made to be backward compatible. Just be ready to update it for Symfony 3.

You can read more about the 2.6 changes for security here:  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.6/UPGRADE-2.6.md

**Symfony 2.3.x**

To accomplish this in Symfony 2.3 you can no longer just set the token in the security context. You also need to save the token to the session.

Assuming a security file with a firewall like:

```
// app/config/security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            //firewall settings here
```

And a controller action similar to:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use YourNameSpace\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class LoginController extends Controller{

    public function registerAction()
    {    
        $user = //Handle getting or creating the user entity likely with a posted form
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main',serialize($token));
        //Now you can redirect where ever you need and the user will be logged in
    }

}
```

For the token creation you will want to create a `UsernamePasswordToken`. This accepts 4 parameters: User Entity, User Credentials, Firewall Name, User Roles. You don't need to provide the user credentials for the token to be valid.

I'm not 100% sure that setting the token on the `security.context` is necessary if you are just going to redirect right away. But it doesn't seem to hurt so I have left it.

Then the important part, setting the session variable. The variables naming convention is `_security_` followed by your firewall name, in this case `main` making `_security_main`.

Comment: I have implemented the code, User successfully logged, but $this->getUser() object returns NULL. Any Idea?

Comment: Crazy things were happening without `$this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));`. Thank you, @Chausser!

Comment: With Symfony 2.6 if you set the token for a firewall named `main` AND you are authenticated with another firewall named `admin` (as you are impersonating the user), a strange thing happens: the `_security_admin` gets the `UsernamePasswordToken` with the user you provided, i.e. you get "disconnected" from your `admin` firewall. Any idea how to maintain the token for "admin" firewall?

Comment: To be honest im not sure of you can be authenticated for 2 firewalls at the same time, ill look into it but in the mean time you should ask a seperate question

Comment: @Chausser it's possible. Imagine you want to login as user /buyer  from your admin panel, without knowing the password and choosing the user from a list. Calling `$tokenStorage->setToken($token)` from your `admin` firewall (read: in admin area covered by `admin` firewall) will serialize the new `UsernamePasswordToken` into the session (`_security_admin`) overriding the previous (you). As a result you're not logged in anymore in `admin`. Instead, setting `$session->set('_security_main', serialize($token))` will work, you end up being logged into `admin` and `main` at the same time.

Comment: @Chausser managed to make it work. You're answer is perfectly right (and it's updated), the only thing it works only when you call `setToken(..)` under the **same target firewall** or **without being authenticated** yet.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the firewall name you can get it via:
`$container->get("security.token_storage")->getToken()->getProviderKey()`
if Symfony version < 2.6 then ->get("security.context")

Comment: That assumes you want to use the current firewall and not a different one, If the route you used to register your user wasnt protected by the firewall you wanted to log the user in against getting it that way wont actually authenticate your user.

Comment: BTW, use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)

Comment: I use symfony 2.7.2 but still need this code to login user => `$this->get('session')->set('_security_main',serialize($token));`

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.8 and the above code authenticates the user in Firefox but not in Chrome. Can there be a difference depending on the browser? Otherwise, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't? I redirect the user right away. Could that be a problem?

Comment: @RayOnAir The above code is browser agnostic, if it works in 1 and not in another then its likely some other issue. You may want to post your own question with some code to see about getting it resolved.

Comment: Symfony 3.3 replaces `security.context` with `security.firewall.context`.

Comment: Thanks for the update @SteveB ill update the answer to reflect this change shortly

Comment: Hi guys, how about the "remember me" feature? Solution provided above do work as for login purpose, but it's in session basis. I try to inject the TokenBasedRememberMeServices and call its method onLoginSuccess which handles the cookie part. But I'm out of lucky and end up with circular reference detected for service. I'm scratching my head now. Does anyone figure it out yet?

Comment: @Nero as that is a slightly different question than this one, you may want to post it as its own question and ill see if i can answer it

Comment: @Chausser here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49684519/symfony-3-3-programmatically-login-a-user-with-remember-me-feature

Comment: Just wanted to drop a quick note for anyone using [firewall contexts](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context). As the answer states, you use the **firewall name**. Don't use the firewall context name. It doesn't work. Log the user in using the current firewall name (as described above) and then they will have access to all firewalls that share the same firewall context.

Answer (score 65):

Figured this one out, finally.

After user registration, you should have access to an object instanceof whatever you've set as your user entity in your provider configuration. The solution is to create a new token with that user entity and pass it into the security context. Here's an example based on my setup:

`RegistrationController.php:`

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($userEntity, null, 'main', array('ROLE_USER'));
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Where `main` is the name of the firewall for your application (thanks, @Joe). That's really all there is to it; the system now considers your user fully logged in as the user they've just created.

EDIT: Per @Miquel's comment, I've updated the controller code sample to include a sensible default role for a new user (though obviously this can be adjusted according to your application's specific needs).

Comment: This isn't quite right with the release version of Symfony 2. You need to pass the user's roles as a fourth argument to the UsernamePasswordToken constructor, or it will be marked as unauthenticated and the user won't have any of their roles.

Comment: What about "Remember me" flag? How to login users by hand, but also they should be logged in forever. This piece of code doesn't solve that issue.

Comment: @maectpo that wasn't in the scope of my original requirements, but sounds like a great followup answer. Let us know what you come up with.

Comment: I have a issue. I can logged in this way, but I the app.user variable is empty. Do you know any way to populate this variable in this login process? - I send the user (string) and password (string) as say the Reference: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.html#method___construct

Comment: Like Marc said below, you need to register the UsernamePasswordToken namespace: `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;`

Comment: Is this working in 2.1? Im using your exact code, but no user is login

Comment: It definitely doesn't work in 2.2. I get an exception "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: A Token was not found in the SecurityContext."

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the firewall name you can get it via:
`$container->get("security.token_storage")->getToken()->getProviderKey()`
if Symfony version < 2.6 then ->get("security.context")

Comment: BTW, use `$this->container->get('security.authorization_checker')` instead (new in 2.6)

Answer (score 6):

If you have a UserInterface object (and that should be the case most of the time) you might want to use the getRoles function that it implements for the last argument.
So if you create a function logUser, it should looks like that:

```
public function logUser(UserInterface $user) {
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
    $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Symfony 2.2 and my experience was slightly different than [Problematic's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5957398/376767), so this is a combined version of all the info from this question plus some of my own.

I think [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7578252/376767) is wrong about the value of `$providerKey`, the third parameter to the `UsernamePasswordToken` constructor. It's supposed to be the key of an authentication (not user) provider. It's used by the authentication system to distinguish between tokens created for different providers.  Any provider which descends from [`UserAuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php#L106) will only authenticate tokens whose provider key matches its own. For example, the [`UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener.php#L88) sets the key of the token it creates to match that of its corresponding [`DaoAuthenticationProvider`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/DaoAuthenticationProvider.php#L45). That lets a single firewall have multiple username+password providers without them stepping on each other. We therefore need to choose a key that won't conflict with any other providers. I use `'new_user'`.

I have a few systems in other parts of my application that depend on the [authentication success event](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/AuthenticationProviderManager.php#L94), and that isn't fired by just setting the token on the context. I had to get the `EventDispatcher` from the container and fire the event manually. I decided against also firing an [interactive login event](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v2.2.0/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AbstractAuthenticationListener.php#L213) because we're authenticating the user implicitly, not in response to an explicit login request.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\AuthenticationEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;

$user = // get a Symfony user instance somehow
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
        $user, null, 'new_user', $user->getRoles() );
$this->get( 'security.context' )->setToken( $token );
$this->get( 'event_dispatcher' )->dispatch(
        AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS,
        new AuthenticationEvent( $token ) );
```

Note that use of `$this->get( .. )` assumes the snippet is in a controller method. If you're using the code somewhere else you'll have to change those to call `ContainerInterface::get( ... )` in a way appropriate to the environment. As it happens my user entities implement `UserInterface` so I can use them directly with the token. If yours don't you'll have to find a way to convert them to `UserInterface` instances.

That code works, but I feel like it's hacking around Symfony's authentication architecture rather than working with it. It would probably be more correct to [implement a new authentication provider](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html) with its own token class rather than hijacking the `UsernamePasswordToken`. Also, using a proper provider would mean that the events were handled for you.

Answer (score 6):

With Symfony 4.4, you can simply do the following in your controller method (see from the Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/guard_authentication.html#manually-authenticating-a-user):

```
// src/Controller/RegistrationController.php
// ...

use App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    public function register(LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator, GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler, Request $request)
    {
        // ...

        // after validating the user and saving them to the database
        // authenticate the user and use onAuthenticationSuccess on the authenticator
        return $guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
            $user,          // the User object you just created
            $request,
            $authenticator, // authenticator whose onAuthenticationSuccess you want to use
            'main'          // the name of your firewall in security.yaml
        );
    }
}
```

**One important thing, make sure your firewall is not set to `lazy`. If it is, the token will never be stored in the session and you will never get logged in.**

```
firewalls:
    main:
        anonymous: ~ # this and not 'lazy'
```

Comment: Only way i got it working with Symfony 5.0, without broken session and redirect errors..

Comment: what's the content of your `use App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator;`  ?

Comment: Only solution working for Symfony 4.4 with guards authenticator, to avoid `"No Authentication Provider found for token of class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken"` when using the latter one

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone has the same follow-on question which kept me coming back to here:

Calling

```
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

only effects the current `security.context` for the route used.

I.e. you can only log in a user from a url within the firewall's control.

(Add an exception for the route if needed - `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY`)

Comment: do you know how you do this for a session? Rather than for just the current request?

Answer (score 2):

As Problematic here already mentioned, this elusive $providerKey parameter is in reality nothing more than the name of your firewall rule, 'foobar' in the case of the example below.

```
firewalls:
    foobar:
        pattern:    /foo/
```

Comment: Can you explain me why if I pass the any string for example `blablabla` as third parameter to UsernamePasswordToken it will works too? what this parameter means?

Comment: This parameter binds your token to a specific firewall provider. In most cases you will only have one provider, so don't bother about it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the answers here and none worked. The only way I could authenticate my users on a controller is by making a subrequest and then redirecting. Here is my code, I'm using silex but you can easily adapt it to symfony2:

```
$subRequest = Request::create($app['url_generator']->generate('login_check'), 'POST', array('_username' => $email, '_password' => $password, $request->cookies->all(), array(), $request->server->all());

$response = $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::MASTER_REQUEST, false);

return $app->redirect($app['url_generator']->generate('curriculos.editar'));
```

Answer (score 1):

On Symfony version 2.8.11 (probably working for older and newer versions), **if you use FOSUserBundle** simply do this :

```
try {
    $this->container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager')->loginUser(
    $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name'), $user, null);
} catch (AccountStatusException $ex) {
    // We simply do not authenticate users which do not pass the user
    // checker (not enabled, expired, etc.).
}
```

No need to dispatch event as I've seen in other solutions.

inpired from FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController::authenticateUser

(from composer.json FOSUserBundle version : "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~1.3")