# Symfony2: How to log user manually?

Tags: symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic post-registration user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication)

I want to log in the user after registration. I can do this by sending POST request with username and password by javascript to /login_check. At least I think it might succeed. But better solution would be achieving it by php code in controller, but I don't know how to do this using Symfony2.

Answer (score 4):

If I remember correctly, the trick is to set the token directly into the `security.context` service. Since you are using a username/password pair, you could instantiate a `UsernamePasswordToken` class and set it in the security context.

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $providerKey, $roles);

$securityContext->setToken($token);
```

For the `$user`, `$password` and `$roles` parameters, it's obvious. For the `$providerKey`, I must admit I don't know what to put in this one exactly. So, maybe getting the token from an `AuthenticationProvider` could be easier, or if maybe you already have access to a `TokenInterface` object.

The main point of my anwser is to set the token directly into the `SecurityContext` object via the method `setToken`. But I'm not sure exactly how to retrieve or create the token :)

Hope this help.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: $providerKey is the name of your firewall, as set in app/config/security.yml