# Symfony2 authentication automatically on Controller or elsewhere

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automatic post-registration user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication)

I made an authentication using my database users and using my own form. The password is encrypted using md5. It worked PERFECTLY.

What i need is authenticate a user by my code on a controller or elsewhere... something like that:

```
$x = $this->get('security.context');
$x->getToken()->setUser($user)->authenticate();
```

If you see, the setUser exists, but i need a really authenticate method.

Thanks

Comment: i found a way, here is the code:

    $token = new \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
    $x = $this->get('security.context');
    $x->setToken($token);

The secured_area parameter is the name of your firewall that do the authentication.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication