# Manual authenticate user

Tags: symfony

I try to authenticate user:

```
<?php 

/**
 * @Route("/testLogin", name="testLogin")
 */
public function testLoginAction()
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('ApplicationDefaultBundle:User')->findOneBy(array('id' => 126));

    $providerKey = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $providerKey, $user->getRoles());

    $this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('testCheck'));
}

/**
 * @Route("/testCheck", name="testCheck")
 */
public function testCheckAction()
{
    if (false === $this->get('security.context')->isGranted(
        'IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'
    )) {
        return new Response('Not logged');
    }
    $user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

    return new Response($user->getUsername.' is logged');
}
```

But I get permanent 302 redirect to /login page.

```
security:
    encoders:
        Application\Bundle\DefaultBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm:   sha512
            iterations: 24
            encode_as_base64: true

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SPECIALIST:  ROLE_USER
        ROLE_EMPLOYER:    ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        main:
            entity: { class: Application\Bundle\DefaultBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

    firewalls:   
        secured_area:
            remember_me:
                key:      MySecretKeyBlablabla
                lifetime: 36000000
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
            pattern:    ^/
            form_login:
                check_path: /login_check
                login_path: /login
                provider: main
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Code for authenticate I take from https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/RegistrationController.php

Error in app/logs/dev.log:

```
redirecting to authentication entry point (No Authentication Provider found for token of class "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken".) [] []
```

I can't access to site until I clean cookies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578674/541961). In your case firewall name is `secured_area`:

```
// your controller action
public function myAction()
{

    // Authenticating user
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    //For Symfony <= 2.3
    //$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    $this->get('session')->set('_security_secured_area', serialize($token));

}
```

Comment: Replace `security.context` with `security.token_storage` in current Symfony versions.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have configured `encoders` section in [security.yml](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#full-default-configuration), as configuration there has changed not very long time ago and it affects your problem.

Comment: I added to my question full security.yml