# How to programmatically login/authenticate a user?

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, symfony-security

I'd like to log the user in right after the registration process, without passing by the login form.

Is this possible ? I've found a solution with `FOSUserBundle`, but I'm not using it on the project I'm actually working on.

Here is my security.yml, I'm working with two firewalls.
The plain text encoder is just for testing.

```
security:
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
        Ray\CentralBundle\Entity\Client: md5

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            users:
                admin: { password: admin, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }
        entity:
            entity: { class: Ray\CentralBundle\Entity\Client, property: email }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        user_login:
            pattern:    ^/user/login$
            anonymous:  ~

        admin_login:
            pattern:    ^/admin/login$
            anonymous:  ~

        admin:
            pattern:    ^/admin
            provider: in_memory
            form_login:
                check_path: /admin/login/process
                login_path: /admin/login
                default_target_path: /admin/dashboard
            logout:
                path:   /admin/logout
                target: /

        site:
            pattern:    ^/
            provider: entity
            anonymous:  ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /user/login/process
                login_path: /user/login
                default_target_path: /user
            logout:
                path:   /user/logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/user/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Comment: If you're not using the FOSUserBundle, which bundle are you actually using?

Comment: @hakre I'm not using any bundle, just a custom User entity that implements UserInterface.

Comment: Please add your `security:` configuration to your question. Mask confidential values.

Comment: @hakre I've added my security.yml file. I'm currently testing richsage answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic post-registration user authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication)

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes, you can do this via something similar to the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken,
    Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

public function registerAction()
{
    // ...
    if ($this->get("request")->getMethod() == "POST")
    {
        // ... Do any password setting here etc

        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        // Here, "public" is the name of the firewall in your security.yml
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "public", $user->getRoles());

        // For older versions of Symfony, use security.context here
        $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);

        // Fire the login event
        // Logging the user in above the way we do it doesn't do this automatically
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

        // maybe redirect out here
    }
}
```

The event firing at the end isn't automatically done when you set a token into the context, whereas it would be normally when using eg a login form or similar.  Hence the reason for including it here.  You may need to adjust the type of token used, depending on your use case - the `UsernamePasswordToken` shown above is a core token, but you can use others if required.

**Edit**: Adjusted the above code to explain the 'public' parameter and also add in the roles of the user into the token creation, based on Franco's comment below.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This seems to be the right way to go, but it does not actually work. Referring to my last edit (the security.yml) I've changed the providerKey (where your is "public" to "entity") but I'm not sure I did the right thing.
When you are saying "you may need to adjust the type of token" I'm not sure to understand.
I've been looking [here](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.html)
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I've found help on [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication) and finally found what was wrong.
**The third parameter is the name of the firewall** and a fourth parameter is needed, wich is an array of roles for the token.
[This worked for me](https://gist.github.com/1974236)

Comment: @FrancoBouly ah great stuff, glad you got it working! I think that firewall parameter may need submitting back to the documentation as I couldn't remember why I'd done it originally :-) Unless I missed reading it entirely ;-)

Comment: Judging by its name, I'm not sure firing that event is the right thing to do. *Interactive* login event, and that's not an interactive login.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @AmrMostafa I believe there's a better way which doesn't use the event, I'll see if I can dig it out and update my answer :-)

Comment: This example from KNPlabs does not require triggering any events and it wroks! http://knplabs.com/blog/redirect-after-registration-in-symfony2/

Comment: Is there a way to keep the user logged in (as if he/she had checked the checkbox in the login form)? Right now if my session expires I get logged out

Comment: @totas there's this issue i don't know but maybe it is useful for you (the issue is still open though) https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/3137

Comment: `$this->get("security.context")` **is deprecated**, use `$this->get('security.token_storage')`

Comment: This will not work properly with latest symfony version. User will be authenticated in the next request instead of the current one. The reason is that ContextListener checks for previous session existence and if not exists it will clear the security TokenStorage. The only way around this (hackish as hell) is to fake the existence of previous session by manually initialising the session (and cookie) on the current request.

Comment: @pinkeen thanks for that - this was back in the 2.1 days I think. I'll add a comment to that effect - do you know what version this would have stopped working from? (I haven't done Symfony dev on anything past 2.7 recently!)

Comment: It did not work for me on 2.2 and 2.3. Don't know about earlier. Will check later when did they overhaul the security system.

Comment: @pinkeen can do add an example for symfony 3.3? I need to loggin user manually

Comment: This appears to cause a PHP memory limit to be exhausted in Symfony 2.8.32.

Answer (score 7):

If you are on symfony ^6.2, you can use `Security::login()`.

For older versions (symfony ^5.4, ^6.0, ^6.1), the following works:

```php
public function login(User $user, Request $request, UserCheckerInterface $checker, UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator, FormLoginAuthenticator $formLoginAuthenticator): void
{
    $checker->checkPreAuth($user);
    $userAuthenticator->authenticateUser($user, $formLoginAuthenticator, $request);
}
```

You may choose to move this functionality into a service so dependency injection is easier:

```yaml
# config/services.yaml

services:
    App\Service\LoginService:
        arguments:
            $formLoginAuthenticator: '@security.authenticator.form_login.main'
```

```php
# src/Service/LoginService.php

namespace App\Service;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\UserAuthenticatorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\FormLoginAuthenticator;

class LoginService
{
    private UserCheckerInterface $checker;
    private UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator;
    private FormLoginAuthenticator $formLoginAuthenticator;

    /**
     * @param UserCheckerInterface $checker
     * @param UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator
     * @param FormLoginAuthenticator $formLoginAuthenticator
     */
    public function __construct(UserCheckerInterface $checker, UserAuthenticatorInterface $userAuthenticator, FormLoginAuthenticator $formLoginAuthenticator)
    {
        $this->checker = $checker;
        $this->userAuthenticator = $userAuthenticator;
        $this->formLoginAuthenticator = $formLoginAuthenticator;
    }


    public function login(User $user, Request $request): void
    {
        $this->checker->checkPreAuth($user);
        $this->userAuthenticator->authenticateUser($user, $this->formLoginAuthenticator, $request);
    }
}
```

Source is an [RFC](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40662) requesting an easier way for programmatic login. This has been [implemented](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/41274), was released with symfony 6.2.

Comment: This also works in Symfony 5.4

Comment: Thank you for testing! I have updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted version will not work with symfony 3.3. User will be authenticated in the next request instead of the current one. The reason is that ContextListener checks for previous session existence and if not exists it will clear the security TokenStorage. The only way around this (hackish as hell) is to fake the existence of previous session by manually initialising the session (and cookie) on the current request.

Let me know if you find a better solution.

BTW I am not sure if this should be merged with the accepted solution.

```
private function logUserIn(User $user)
{
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "common", $user->getRoles());
    $request = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest();

    if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
        $request->setSession($this->session);
        $request->getSession()->start();
        $request->cookies->set($request->getSession()->getName(), $request->getSession()->getId());
    }

    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    $this->session->set('_security_common', serialize($token));

    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($this->requestStack->getMasterRequest(), $token);
    $this->eventDispatcher->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
}
```

The above code assumes that your firewall name (or shared context name) is `common`.

Comment: The right way is to set require_previous_session to false in firewall `form_login: require_previous_session: false`

Comment: I would've to check. But I have a vague memory that I tried that and it didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : [For Symfony 3 users](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/459/how-to-authenticate-login-manually-an-user-in-a-controller-with-or-without-fosuserbundle-on-symfony-3), do not forget to make this correction to test the equality of the passwords (as the method shown to test the password on this link is not working) :

```
$current_password = $user->getPassword();
$user_entry_password = '_got_from_a_form';

$factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');
$encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);
$password = $encoder->encodePassword($user_entry_password, $user->getSalt());

if(hash_equals($current_password, $password)){
//Continue there
}

// I hash the equality process for more security
```

+ info : [hash_equals_function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-equals.php)

Answer (score 0):

For Symfony 5, you can use out of the box functionalities to create login and registration forms.

- How to create login form: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
- How to create registration form: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/registration_form.html

Using Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler is key point.

You can use GuardAuthenticatorHandler in registration controller after successful registration. It logs in user and redirects to page defined in onAuthenticationSuccess from LoginFormAuthenticator.

Below, I added some code snippets.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Login;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class LoginController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {     
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="app_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        throw new \LogicException('This method can be blank - it will be intercepted by the logout key on your firewall.');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $credentials['email']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $credentials['password']);
    }

    /**
     * Used to upgrade (rehash) the user's password automatically over time.
     */
    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));

//        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
//            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_homepage'));
//        }
//
//        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('some_route'));
//        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorHandler;

class RegistrationController extends AbstractController
{
    private EntityManagerInterface $objectManager;

    private UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder;

    private GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler;

    private LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator;

    /**
     * RegistrationController constructor.
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @param GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler
     * @param LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator
     */
    public function __construct(
        EntityManagerInterface $objectManager,
        UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder,
        GuardAuthenticatorHandler $guardHandler,
        LoginFormAuthenticator $authenticator
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
        $this->guardHandler = $guardHandler;
        $this->authenticator = $authenticator;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/registration")
     */
    public function displayRegistrationPage()
    {
        return $this->render(
            'registration/registration.html.twig',
            );
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/register", name="app_register")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
//        if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('sth-special', $request->request->get('token'))) {
//            return $this->render(
//                'registration/registration.html.twig',
//                ['errorMessage' => 'Token is invalid']
//            );
//        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->setEmail($request->request->get('email'));
        $user->setPassword(
            $this->passwordEncoder->encodePassword(
                $user,
                $request->request->get('password')
            )
        );
        $user->setRoles(['ROLE_USER']);

        $this->objectManager->persist($user);
        $this->objectManager->flush();

        return $this->guardHandler->authenticateUserAndHandleSuccess(
            $user,
            $request,
            $this->authenticator,
            'main' // firewall name in security.yaml
        );

        return $this->render('base.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After several days of debugging and investigating I finally authenticate a user programmatically on Symfony 4.4. I guess this approach should also work on the newer versions too.

Important to get the correct name of the firewall, `main` in my case, in your `security.yml`

```yaml
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            #...
```

and then pass it into the session:

```php
$session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
```

The full code of login action:

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationProviderManager;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Session\SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface;
//...

public function loginAction(
    Request $request,
    TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
    SessionAuthenticationStrategyInterface $sessionStrategy,
    AuthenticationProviderManager $authManager
) {
    // ...
    if ($request->getMethod() == "POST") {
        // Fetching user and checking password logic...
        $em->flush();

        // Create an authenticated token for the User.
        // Here, "main" is the name of the firewall in your security.yml
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken(
            $email,
            $password,
            'main', // firewall name in security.yaml
            $user->getRoles()
        );

        $session = $request->getSession();
        if (!$request->hasPreviousSession()) {
            $request->setSession($session);
            $request->getSession()->start();
            $request->cookies->set($request->getSession()->getName(), $request->getSession()->getId());
        }

        $session->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $email);

        // Authenticate user
        $authManager->authenticate($token);
        $sessionStrategy->onAuthentication($request, $token);

        // For older versions of Symfony, use "security.context" here
        $tokenStorage->setToken($token);
        $session->set('_security_main', serialize($token));

        $session->remove(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        $session->remove(Security::LAST_USERNAME);

        // Fire the login event
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get('event_dispatcher')->dispatch($event, SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN);

        // return success response here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->get('fos_user.security.login_manager')->logInUser('main', $user);
```

Where `'main'` is the name of your firewall in `security.yml`, and `$user` is the object representing the user you want to log in.

This works in my Symfony 2.8 project, you can check for the login_manager service in your version by running `php app/console debug:container`.