# How to programmatically authenticate a user

Tags: symfony

I have a controller that is supposed to add a user through a simple form, but I cannot get the user to be manually authenticated.

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken    

public function addAction($user)
    {
           $token =new UsernamePasswordToken(
                    $user->getUsername(),
                    $user->getPassword(),
                    'secured_area',
                   $user->getRoles()
                    );

           $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
           // as suggested in some other answers

           $request->getSession()->set('_security_secured_area', serialize($token));
           // as suggested in http://techblog.zabuchy.net/2012/manually-authenticate-symfony-2-user/

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('acme_project_secure_show' )
                    );
        }
    }
```

The redirection to the secure route works, but then the method `$this->getUser()` returns null as the authentication is not set properly...
I can get the user from `$user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken();` instead of `$user= $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();` shortcut for `$this->getUser()`  see the Book [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object)
Any idea why?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550079/programmatically-login-user

Comment: Does your user have any roles?  It needs at least one for token to be considered authenticated.  Don't do that session stuff.  The security context listener takes care of that.  Use the debug toolbar and see if the security token makes it into the session.

Comment: what is your firewall config ? the security context is specific for each firewall. maybe you are redirecting to a url which is not behind the same firewall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved - two points were missing: 1) it was necessary to dispatch the `InteractiveLoginEvent` -thanks mpm for the link 2) the route of this controller was not under the `secured_area` firewall - merci Florian ;)

Comment: Another error you made was the first parameter of UsernamePassworkToken needs the whole user object instead of only the username!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "firewallname", $user->getRoles());
```

Comment: yeah, the namespace is set correctly - see update

Answer (score -1):

As said @user19340357, you can instanciate a token by hand.

What he forgot to say is that you should set it in the security context:

```php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken

$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), "firewallname", $user->getRoles());
$securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context'); // do it your way
$securityContext->setToken($token);
```

Comment: I don't see the difference from what I'm doing.  `$this->getUser()` is still null