# Symfony2. Forwarding to login_check in isn't interceipted

Tags: php, security, symfony

I would like to authentificate user after its registration.

So *registrationAction* is:

```
public function registrationAction(Request $request) {
    //Creating user...

    return $this->forward('AcmeFrontBundle:Mobile:securityCheck', array(
        '_username' => $customer->getEmail(),
        '_password' => 'pwd',
    ));
}
```

The problem is that Symfony security system doesn't interceipt this redirecting, but executes directly *securityCheckAction* which is naturally empty.

Redirection works in that way:

```
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('mobile_login_check') . "?_username=" . $customer->getEmail() . "&_password=pass");
```

Forwarding is preferable because I would like to use POST request for *registrationAction* and *securityCheckAction*.

Any ideas?

In the other hand maybe it would be better to authentificate user by myself? Just like described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/testing/simulating_authentication.html

What is your opinion?

Comment: have a look at FOSUserBundle. It provides all this functionality and masses more.

Comment: I just used `$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($customer, $customer->getPassword(), 'secured_mobile', $customer->getRoles()); $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);`. This is simple and effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to perform a redirect with POST is not a good idea. Here's why:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/99894/why-doesnt-http-have-post-redirect

The best way is to create token & emit login event:
[How to programmatically login/authenticate a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550079/how-to-programmatically-login-authenticate-a-user)