# Symfony2 - external login form with CSRF token?

Tags: php, symfony, csrf, fosuserbundle

fellow Symfonians.

I need to integrate my system's login with client's login form, which exists already on their page and was used for their old systems. I use FOSUserBundle with custom view for login form, but unfortunately they want to keep their login form as is ("for reasons"). It's not even on the same server.

Is there a way to pass my CSRF login token to their form (I have the access to their code), or do I have to disable CSRF on my login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm aware that his is not an answer to your specific question `Is there a way to pass my CSRF login token to their form?` but rather a different way of achieving a login from an external form.

You can login programmatically: [How to programmatically login/authenticate a user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550079/how-to-programmatically-login-authenticate-a-user)

The answer uses a "register" action, but it's similar for you. The important part is this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $password, "public", $user->getRoles());
$this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token);

$event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
$this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

which will login the user.

Comment: So basically I would have to create separate controller action for that external form, which would at first validate the user/pass data and then dispatch login event? I'm not sure it's perfect for my strange case (I've got some on-login redirects to other systems, but fortunately on interactive_login event, so it may work), but I will check it, it may be the solution, thanks.