# Log in user, without form submit (Symfony 3)

Tags: php, security, authentication, doctrine, symfony

I have a `User` entity, which implements `UserInterface, \Serializable, EquatableInterface`

It is set in the security settings:

```
security:

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: sha512

    providers:
        our_db_provider:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: email

    firewalls:
        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: our_db_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/ , roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/registration, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        #...
```

I would like to select a user from the database and log in the current visitor, as the selected user.

```
$user = $em->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->find($user_id);
```

I have no idea, how to manage it. I am not using `FOSUserBundle`. I've searched for the solution, but I can't found anything, just the `AuthenticationUtils`, which only works with form submits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically login/authenticate a user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550079/how-to-programmatically-login-authenticate-a-user)

Comment: You might be asking how to switch to a user: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html

Answer (score 1):

In \Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\UsernamePasswordFormAuthenticationListener you can find lines that shows how to make authorization manually without performing a form submit:

`$request->getSession()->set(Security::LAST_USERNAME, $username);`

`return $this->authenticationManager->authenticate(new UsernamePasswordToken($username, $password, $this->providerKey));`

`$this->providerKey` can be taken from `security.yml` as a key from **firewalls** section.

If firewalls section looks like

```
    firewalls:
      secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
          check_path: login_check
          login_path: login
        logout:
          path:   /logout
```

then providerKey = **secured_area**.

authenticationMananger can be taken from **security.authentication.manager** service.

Hope it will work!