# Test user connected in Symfony / PhpUnit

Tags: symfony, testing

In my controller, I use the security.token_storage service to get the user connected like :

`$client = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$username = $client->getNom()." ".$client->getPrenom();`

In my functional test, I try to log in a user to retrieve it in my controller but if I debug inside, it says me that i'm anonymous :

```
private function logIn()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $firewallName = 'main';
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken("admin", "admin", "main", array());
    static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $session = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('session');
    $session->set('_security_'.$firewallName, serialize($token));
    $session->save();
    $cookie = new Cookie($session->getName(), $session->getId());
    $client->getCookieJar()->set($cookie);

    return $client;
}

public function testIndex()
{
    $client = $this->logIn();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/');
    $login = $crawler->filter("#username_index")->text();
    $this->assertEquals($login, 'ADMIN NOM Admin Prenom');
}
```

How i can pass my user of my test to my main code ?

Comment: Could you please write what do you want to test?

Comment: edit your post to add the code you commented ;)

Comment: You're missing something. Take a look at this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550079/how-to-programmatically-login-authenticate-a-user) to know what.

Comment: @DonCallisto I try but doesn't work... to tell the truth maybe I don't use it correctly...

Comment: OK, but why you are using `PHPUnit` for functional tests?

Comment: @KamilAdryjanek is not that uncommon ...

Comment: Have you followed this documentation?
https://symfony.com/doc/current/testing/http_authentication.html
You need to add a `http_basic: ~` variable in your test environment

Comment: @NathanMeyer it's not this method that I use, in this documentation, I use the second solution.

Comment: Ok, I see something more `$token = new UsernamePasswordToken("admin", "admin", "main", array());` 
Why don't you declare a role here ?

Comment: It's the same with or without roles...

Comment: @Topheur If you don't declare a role I don't think your user will have any user role : https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.php