# Symfony 3.4: Redirection issue

Tags: symfony, redirect

I’m facing one issue in redirection.

**Step:**

•   Admin user send one payment link to customer and customer must be login and pay amount.
•   Customer click on link and redirect to login screen because customer is not not in system. But I want if user come for payment link then after login customer must be redirected to that link.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To stop the login redirection you have to add one access_control in your config/packages/security.yaml like [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html) suggest:
`- { path: ^/payment, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}`

After that you can take the parameters and do the login (or whatever your process is) like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550079/how-to-programmatically-login-authenticate-a-user) does.