# Symfony2 auto-login after registration

Tags: authentication, symfony-2.1, user-registration

I already searched [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication), but it didn't help me.

How to authenticate user after registration? 
Where is my error?

security.yml

```
security:

    providers:
      #chain_provider is used here to implement a multiple firewalls in future: admins, accounts ...
      chain_provider:
        chain:
          providers: [admins,accounts]
      admins:
        entity: { class: FME\Bundle\_CoreBundle\Entity\Admin, property: username }
      accounts:
        entity: { class: FME\Bundle\_CoreBundle\Entity\Account, property: email }

    encoders:
        FME\Bundle\_CoreBundle\Entity\Admin: sha512
        FME\Bundle\_CoreBundle\Entity\Account: sha512

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        #no firewall for the Login page
        admin_area_login:
          pattern:  ^/admin/login$
          security: false

        admin_area:
            pattern:    ^/admin/
            provider: admins
            form_login:
                check_path: fme_aa_login_handler
                login_path: fme_aa_login
            logout:
                path:   fme_aa_logout
                target: fme_aa_login
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

        #no firewall for the Login page
        account_area_login:
          pattern:  ^/account/login$
          security: false

        account_area:
            pattern:    ^/account/
            provider: accounts
            form_login:
                check_path: fme_aca_login_handler
                login_path: fme_aca_login
            logout:
                path:   fme_aca_logout
                target: fme_aca_login
```

The controller for registration is the following:

```
namespace FME\Bundle\FtdBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

use FME\Bundle\_CoreBundle\Entity\Account;
use FME\Bundle\FtdBundle\Form\RegistrationType;

/**
 * @Route("/registration")
 */
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{      
    /**
     * Account registration
     * 
     * @Route("/",name="fme_ftd_registration")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $account = new Account();

        //set default role group
        $account->setRoleGroup($this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('FMECoreBundle:AccountRoleGroup')->findDefault());

        //default company type from the FMECoreBundle is used
        $form = $this->createForm(new RegistrationType(), $account);

        if ($request->isMethod('POST'))
        {
            $form->bind($request);

            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($account);

                //encode password using current encoder
                $password = $encoder->encodePassword($form->get('password')->getData(), $account->getSalt());

                //set encrypted password
                $account->setPassword($password);

                //save an object in the DB
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($account);
                $em->flush();

                //send the token to account via email
                if (! $this->_sendVerificationToken($account))
                {
                    $this->get('session')->setFlash('error', 
                        $this->get('translator')->trans('Error sending the verification token.')
                    );
                }

                $this->get('session')->setFlash('success', 
                    $this->get('translator')->trans('Your account was created. Please check you inbox to verify the email.')
                );

                //Automatic post-registration user authentication
                $this->_authenticateAccount($account);

                //redirect to home page in the account area
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('fme_aca_dashboard'));
            }
        }

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }

    /**
     * Send the token to verify an account email
     */
    protected function _sendVerificationToken(Account $account)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    /**
     * Automatic post-registration user authentication
     */
    protected function _authenticateAccount(Account $account)
    {
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($account, null, 'account_area', $account->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all make sure that registration page fits one of firewalls. Than append additional parameter for each firewall:

```
context: <string>
```

Like this:

```
    account_area_login:
        ...
        context: administration

    admin_area:
        ...
        context: administration
```

Context allows to share authentication cookie among different firewalls. So to keep user authenticated after registration, firewall of registration page and other firewalls should have identical context.

Comment: But I don't understand why I need to specify an `account_area` firewall key as third parameter if It's unnecessary because setToken() only effects the current 'security.context' for the route used?

Comment: I mean, I can pass the `blablabla` instead of `account_area` and it will works too. Do you know why?

Comment: Third parameter is not a firewall key. It is a provider key. It is used by authentication provider to match supported tokens. E.g. to provide authentication by username/password and with facebook account requires different implementation of tokens and different providers.

Comment: Hmmm. So, whether third parameter must match with the provider name in the security.yml?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not an expert in Symfony authentication and could be wrong, but I think provider key does not matter unless you are using remember me service.