# Automatically login in Symfony2 with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, authentication, authorization, fosuserbundle

I have created an individual sign up mechanism in my Symfony2 app (using FOSUserBundle) which exists in addition to the regular registration.

Is there any way - after I have created and persisted the User to the database - to automatically login that current user. And after that the User shall be redirected to a page which requires a logged in user (and due to the automatical login, the User can access that page)?

This is basically my method to create the user:

```
public function signupAction(Request $request) {
    $user = new User();

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($user)
                ->...()
                ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // Enable User
        $user->setEnabled(true);

        // Persist to DB
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();

        // Here I need the auto-login before redirecting to _root

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_root'));
    }

    return $this->render('MyBundle:MyController:signup.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Attention: This doesn't seem to work in Symfony3 anymore.*

Quoting from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19578674/1828051) to a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5886713/1828051):

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

$user = //Handle getting or creating the user entity likely with a posted form
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$this->get('session')->set('_security_main',serialize($token));
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Symfony 3.1

Comment: @AlexeyKosov , worked for me in Symfony 3.1 by using `security.token_storage` instead of `security.context`

Comment: there is a simpler and cleaner solution with FOSUserBundle : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44386575/592477