# User authentication on Symfony2 without saving to Database

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

How can I make Symfony 2 user authentication using external user authentication service (UAS)?

Here is the plan:

1. Enter Login and Password;
2. Press Submit button;
3. Symfony 2 send request to auth. service (Login and Password);
4. Symfony 2 receives user status from auth. service (access/no access);
5. User login with ROLE_USER without saving user data to database.

Any solutions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write your custom authentication provider in Symfony to achieve something like that.

I already answered to the same topic here: 
[Symfony 2.4/FOSUserBundle - is there a way to hook into the login process programatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23962661/symfony-2-4-fosuserbundle-is-there-a-way-to-hook-into-the-login-process-progra)

And here's the Symfony tutorial explaining and detailing a scenario: 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html