# Can't start Session in Symfony2 with UsernamePasswordToken

Tags: php, symfony, session, symfony-2.4

I'm about to be crazy with an error in Symfony2.4 login with UsernamePasswordToken...

I have on my site to autologin users with their URL and a Hash of their user. The Action is very simple, and the only think that I do (after some checks) is:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

With this, in some cases it works (when I try it always works...) but in some cases doesn't works... The log in this cases says:

```
[2014-10-30 15:47:25] request.INFO: Matched route "_my_route" (parameters: "_controller": "MyController", "url": "my-url", "hash": "2f5fccc7b5fc2d41bbc3e1e469655f24f540e383", "_route": "_my_route") [] []
[2014-10-30 15:47:25] security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
[2014-10-30 15:47:25] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
[2014-10-30 15:47:25] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by "/route/app/bootstrap.php.cache" at line 1365." at /route/app/cache/prod/classes.php line 119 {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException: Failed to start the session because headers have already been sent by \"/route/app/bootstrap.php.cache\" at line 1365. at /route/app/cache/prod/classes.php:119)"} []
[2014-10-30 15:47:25] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

Why headers have already sent? Why only in some cases? Somebody knows frequently cases when it happens?

I tried a lot of things: check that no characters printed before this, change firewalls in security.yml, put sessions in disk file, ...

I think that all is OK.

My User Entity:

```
class MyUser implements UserInterface, \Serializable
{
...
/**
 * Serializes the user.
 *
 * The serialized data have to contain the fields used byt the equals method.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function serialize()
{
    return serialize(array(
        $this->id,
        $this->password,
        $this->email
    ));
}

/**
 * Unserializes the user.
 *
 * @param string $serialized The serialized string
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function unserialize($serialized)
{
    list(
        $this->id,
        $this->password,
        $this->email
    ) = unserialize($serialized);
}
...
```

Security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
    MyProject\PublicBundle\Entity\MyUser:
        algorithm:   sha1
        iterations: 1
        encode_as_base64: false

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        ROLE_PENDING
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: MyProject\PublicBundle\Entity\MyUser, property: email }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            failure_path: /login
            username_parameter: email
            password_parameter: password
            default_target_path: /login-redirect
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key:      "aSecretKey"
            lifetime: 321408000
            path:     /
            domain:   %domain%
```

config.yml (session section was added after first errors)

```
framework:
secret:          "%secret%"
router:
    resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
    strict_requirements: ~
form:            ~
csrf_protection: ~
validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
templating:
    engines: ['twig']
default_locale:  "%locale%"
trusted_hosts:   ~
trusted_proxies: ~
session:
    handler_id: session.handler.native_file
    save_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/sessions"
fragments:       ~
http_method_override: true
```

Comment: Can you provide also section framework from config.yml?

Comment: What is on "/route/app/bootstrap.php.cache" at line 1365."

Comment: I updated with framework of config.yml. Is the sendContent function echo:
public function sendContent()
{
echo $this->content; //1365
return $this;
}. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This likely has to do with how you are trying to save the token to the session.

Are you using the service like:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$this->get('session')->set('_security_secured_area',serialize($token));
```

[Automatic post-registration user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication/19578674#19578674)

Comment: Thank you! I think that this solved the problem. I will continue trying ti :D