# Interactive login in Symfony 2.6 looses credentials after redirect

Tags: symfony

I am new to Symfony so it may well be that my question is the result of a simple error but I have been searching for an answer for quite a while with no success.

I am trying to log in a user that requests for a new password with a temporary token.

The relevant part of my controller is:

```
// auto log in the user
  $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'main', $user->getRoles());
  $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token);

  // do the the login event
  $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
  $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

  return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('nononsense_home_homepage'));
```

If I get the user info with getUser before the redirect I can see that the **credentials of the logged user are there** but they are lost as soon as the redirect takes place.

Curiously enough if I purposedly include an error in the target page whenever symfony throws the errror I can check theat I am logged with the right credentials in the symfony dev bar!!! But if I correct the error and reload the page again I can see in the dev bar that the user is not authenticated any longer.

**Firewall**

```
main:
        pattern: ^/
        provider: main
        form_login:
            check_path: /users/check_user
            login_path: /users/login
            remember_me: true
            default_target_path: /users/login_init
        logout:
            path:   /users/logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            key: Qn65f7wtgGZKCCzWQZps04AskmNSiZrvl3qVZRCCIp
            lifetime: 31536000
            path: /
            domain: ~
        anonymous: false
        switch_user: true
```

If you need any other chunk of code just let me know...

Comment: Is your route behind the firewall called `main`?

Comment: Yes I will edit the question to include the firewall settings.

Comment: excuse me, can you post the `access_control` section of the `security.yml` also? The path of the route must be configured with a role

Comment: The access_control is empty because I want to allow any authenticated user to get in. By the way, when the users authenticate with the login form they have no problem to access the app.

Comment: Try adding this access control rule: `- { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Comment: Last difference with some confs in my projects is that my firewall have `anonymous: ~` instead of your `anonymous: false`. I don't know if this can help... :(

Comment: I aleady tried that :-( The problem is not an access problem but that the session Token is lost for some unknown reasons to me. Anyhow, thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct answer in [Automatic post-registration user authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication).

It has taken a while but I moved to different things and I retook the issue again to find that it was answered in this post.