# FOS UserBundle User Manager - login after updateUser

Tags: php, authentication, fosuserbundle, symfony, usermanager

I would like to ask whether the package Fos UserBundle when you add a user, you can log it with the user manager? If so, in what way?

```
$userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();
$user -> setUsername('test');
$user -> setEmail('test');
$user -> setPlainPassword('test');
$user ->setEnabled(true);
$userManager->updateUser($user, true);`
```

`

Comment: Do you mean log the `updateUser` call?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic post-registration user authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
$loginManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.security.login_manager');
$firewallName =  $this->container->getParameter('fos_user.firewall_name');
$loginManager->loginUser($firewallName, $user);
```

Thanks for help