# auto login with fosuserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, autologin

I can do auto login with fosuserBundle,when he access the page adding clause he is auto login , When he accéd page adding article he redirect automatically to the login page but my objective is to auto login

routing :

```
ajouterapps:
  path:     /ajouterapps
  defaults: { _controller: MedBundle:Apps:ajouter }
```

code controller :

```
public function ajouterAction() 
{
  $em = $this->getDoctrine();
  $repo  = $em->getRepository("UserBundle:User"); //Entity Repository
  $user = $this->getUser();

  if (!$user) {
    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
  } else {
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "your_firewall_name", $user->getRoles());
    $this->get("security.context")->setToken($token); //now the user is logged in

    //now dispatch the login event
    $request = $this->get("request");
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
    $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
  }

  $msg = 'ajouter Apps';
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $app = new Apps();
  $form = $this->createForm(new AppsType, $app);
  $request = $this->getRequest();

  if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $app->upload(); 
    $em->persist($app);
    $em->flush();
    $msg = 'Apps ajouter avec success';
  }

  return $this->render('MedBundle:Apps:ajouter.html.twig',array(
      'form'=>$form->createView(),
      'msg'=>$msg
    )
  );
}
```

What is the solution and thank you in advance

Comment: help me please ...

Comment: See full answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886713/automatic-post-registration-user-authentication

Comment: thank you for help ,I see this subject but I find the same problem that when he accéd page adding Article I find login page that is to say Auto Login is not walk

Comment: What is "your firewall name" on main app config.yml ?

Comment: this is my firewall in app/config/config.yml

Comment: firewall_name: main

Comment: Try to replace "your_firewall_name" by "main".

Comment: Have you try to have a look to errors log ?

Comment: my firwall is : 

firewall_name: main

Comment: $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "**your_firewall_name**", $user->getRoles());